# Is there a mathematical property which could help "sum up" information from certain matrix areas?

Tags: matrices, programming

I have a matrix

$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 4 \\
-3 & 8 & -5\\
12 & -7 & 16
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and I would like to create the matrix

$$B=
\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 5 & 6 \\
11 & 26 & 15\\
10 & 21 & 12
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where each entry of B is the sum of its surrounding cells in $A$. So the first entry of $B$ is $2-1-3+8=6$. The $3\times 3$ matrix and the summing "radius" are a simplification, the question aims at $m \times n$ matrices along with arbitrary rectangular areas to be measured.

Is there some mathematical property which could help avoid having to implement something along the lines of
$$b_{kl}=\sum_{l-a}^{l+b}\sum_{k-c}^{k+d}a_{kl} ~~~\text{given that the entries exist}$$
? Special case: would things be easier if the entries only consisted of a fixed amount of $0$ and $1$?

Comment: You are going to have to do a lot of adding up however you approach it. If $m\times n$ is large and adjacent rectangles have substantial overlap you could take advantage of that (by just calculating the difference).

Comment: Why? Programming what?

Comment: @WillJagy Minesweeper and possible generalizations.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is essentially a  [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of $2$-dim array of data using a $3 \times 3$ kernel.

For really large array and arbitrary kernel, one can use [discrete fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) to speed up the computation.

In the case where the kernel is not too big, rectangular and binary ( i.e weight $1$ if inside rectangle, $0$ otherwise), one can use the trick of sum table to compute the sum.

Given any array of data $a_{xy}$, define
$$\Delta(x_0,y_0;x_1,y_1) = \sum_{x = x_0}^{x_1} \sum_{y = y_0}^{y_1} a_{xy}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
\Delta_0(x,y) = \Delta(0,0;x,y)$$ 
These functions satisfy:
$$\begin{align}
\Delta(x_0,y_0;x_1,y_1) &= \Delta_0(x_1,y_1) - \Delta_0(x_0-1,y_1) - \Delta_0(x_1,y_0-1) + \Delta_0(x_0-1,y_0-1)\\
\Delta_0(x_0,y_0) &= \Delta_0(x_0,y_0-1) + \sum_{x=0}^{x_0} a_{xy_0}
\end{align}
$$
Let's say you have an $N_1 \times N_2$ array of data and you want to convolute it with a $M_1 \times M_2$ rectangular binary kernel.
You can build the sum table $\Delta_0$ by scanning along the rows,
storing the most recent seen $M_2+1$ rows of $\Delta_0$ and compute
the $\Delta$ using row sums from current row and the previous $M_2+1$-th row. In this way, you can compute all the $\Delta$ sums in $O(N_1 \times N_2)$ steps using $O(N_1 \times M_2)$ working storage.

You should browse over the questions tagged with 
[convolution](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convolution)
on [dsp.SE (Signal processing)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) to see whether
there are some library you can use.